# Is there a standard for the message when deprecating a type or method with another

Tags: c#, .net, standards, deprecated, obsolete

I use:

```
[Obsolete("Please use [NEW API] instead.")]
```

to deprecate public APIs, but I'm not sure what is the standard for **[NEW API]**.
The following examples seem to be pretty standard:

```
[Obsolete("Please use Method2() instead.")] //This seems to be ok if Method2 is in the same class
[Obsolete("Please use Class2.Method1() instead.")] //This seems to be ok if we are referencing a different class in the same namespace
[Obsolete("Please use Namespace.Class2.Method1() instead.")] //This seems to be ok if we are referencing a different class in a different namespace
```

But it starts to get blurry when you are replacing the API with a specific method with args:

```
[Obsolete("Please use Method2(string, string) instead.")]
```

Is that the correct way to reference a specific method type or do I include the variable names? Eg:

```
[Obsolete("Please use Method2(string arg1, string arg2) instead.")]
```

And now the harder one, how about if the type has been moved to another assembly, eg:

```
[Obsolete("Please use Namespace.ClassName.Method2(), AssemblyName instead.")]
[Obsolete("Please use AssemblyName!Namespace.ClassName.Method2() instead.")]
```

Which one is the correct way, or is there another way?

Comment: If it's a complicated enough situation, another alternative is to put up a page describing the various use cases and what they should consider changing to, then just put the url (something permanent!) in the message. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track and this is in line what I have done in the past. I have often felt like there could be more overloads to ObsoleteAttribute (perhaps multiple attributes meaning slightly different things even?). Take a look at some examples from the .NET framework that are doing exactly what you mention:

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("This class has been deprecated. Please use System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202")]
public sealed class XslTransform

[Obsolete("Please use Hashtable(int, float, IEqualityComparer) instead.")] 
public Hashtable(int capacity, float loadFactor, IHashCodeProvider hcp, IComparer comparer) : this(capacity, loadFactor) {
```